# Android Studio 0.2.9 and New Project

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio for app development and i am using it from its 1st release, i keep updating it whenever a patch is available.Recently I updated my android studio to latest version , that is 0.2.9 and now i am facing problem while creating new project.

every time i am getting this exception msg box

```
The following dependencies were not resolvable. See your build.gradle file for details.
    - com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0
```

and i am clueless about what went wrong !!

p.s : previous projects are working fine

seeking suggestions on it :)

Comment: Just FYI, you are referring to version 0.2.9

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Make sure you download the Android Support Repository under **`Extras`** using the **SDK Manager**
   [image: Android SDK Manager]
2. The in your project module look for the second `build.gradle` file uncomment the `dependencies` section that is pointed in your case, the file provides some instruction on what you have to do. [image: Android Studio]
3. With that in place save, build and test, happy coding!

Comment: you are welcome @r4jiv007 Android Studio is too rough at this time

Comment: Note: After uncommenting that line, you need to sync your project with Gradle Files, which is the button right next to project structure.